# How to write HTML code in ABAP to send a mail

Tags: html, css, abap

Can any one help me writing this code in HTML with specified spaces and conditions when given in ABAP. I am including HTML in ABAP to send a mail through ABAP.

Here I need to print `flds-fieldname` after 10 spaces as mentioned in the below write statement. I need to write in HTML.

```
loop at flds .
  assign component flds-fieldname of structure l_det to <fl>.
  assign component flds-fieldname of structure r_det to <fr>.
  if <fl> ne <fr>.
    write : /10 flds-fieldname ,
            /20 'Local -' , 30 <fl> ,
            /20 'Remote -' , 30 <fr> .
  endif.
endloop.

uline.
skip.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have difficulties, what did you try? 1) Is that a pure HTML question? 2) Do you ask how to send an email? 3) Or how to send the main text in HTML format? [stackoverflow only answers precise questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi Sandra I need to send a mail so the text content should be like field name new line 20 space local system detail  30 space new line 20 space remote details 30 space I am trying to write using concatenate but I am unable to assign fields and spaces in html format.

Comment: Could you update your question please, the code you show does not contain `concatenate`. Anyway, your question looks to be about HTML. HTML rendering shows only one space when the source has several contiguous spaces. There are several strategies to render exact spaces, the main ones are to use `&nbsp;` (Non-Breaking SPace) in place of each space, or use the CSS style `white-space:pre`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a suitable & maintainable code, I advise you to separate html content and ABAP content. For that you can use the `SAP Web Repository`.

---

First write your `html` page

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <!var!>
            Local - fl
            ...
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can insert placeholder like `<!var!>` and replace them with `ABAP` variables in the driver program.

---

Secondly download it in the `SAP Web Repository` with the transaction `SMW0`

---

Finally load your html page with appropriate function module in your driver program

```
call function 'WWW_HTML_MERGER'
      exporting
        template           = 'YOUR_SWR_HTML_ID_TEXT'
*       MERGE_TEXTPOOL     =
*       TEMPLATE_TABLE     =
      importing
        html_table         = lv_text
      changing
        merge_table        = lt_merge
      exceptions
        template_not_found = 1
        others             = 2.
    if sy-subrc <> 0.
      raise exception type cx_swf_mail_manager.
    endif.
```

change argument `TEMPLATE` by your `template ID` in `SAP Web Repository`
`html` placeholder are replaced in the internal table lt_merge